# Marionette View Structure

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have to create a page with two sections . One to display the step information and other the content of the step. Where the first section remains same through out the flow i.e., step section. The second section should contain the content of the step .

In first step it should display the grid and once the rows are selected and next is clicked it should display the content of second step and finally third step content on next click in the second step.

When i move back and forth the content section data should be carried to other views and should be persist the selected data when i come back to the previous step.

I divided the page into two regions one for step and other for content. Created 3 itemViews for the content of 3 steps. which i am assigning to the content section.Kindly let me know how do i pass and persist data when i move forward and backward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marionette works really well having views tied to models for persisting data. As long as each of your views has access to the model instance you'll be able to view the current model state at each step.

If you need the first section to also update based on the information put in by the user at each step, you should check out [Model Binder](https://github.com/theironcook/Backbone.ModelBinder) which allows you to tie any attribute of a model to any jQuery selector for auto updating the display based on the value of the attribute.